UnsatisfiedLinkError when I am trying to load a .so file to my docker/podman container
I am trying to run a java spring boot application inside a podman container(similar to docker container). The jar file contains all dependencies, and one of the dependency includes a .so (libturbojpeg.so) library in it. When I run the image, it throw the following exception:
ERROR c.s.t.c.s.JpegTurboLibServiceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0  - no libturbojpeg in java.library.path: /libjpeg-turbo/bin/
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libturbojpeg in java.library.path: /libjpeg-turbo/bin/
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2434)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1993)
        at org.libjpegturbo.turbojpeg.TJLoader.load(TJLoader.java:33)
        at org.libjpegturbo.turbojpeg.TJDecompressor.<clinit>(TJDecompressor.java:1170)
        at com.sice.turbolib.config.service.JpegTurboLibServiceConfig.tjDecompressor(JpegTurboLibServiceConfig.java:20)
        at com.sice.turbolib.config.service.JpegTurboLibServiceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$tjDecompressor$3(<generated>)
        at com.sice.turbolib.config.service.JpegTurboLibServiceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
        at com.sice.turbolib.config.service.JpegTurboLibServiceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.tjDecompressor(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
        at com.sice.log.aspects.SiceLoggerAspect.profile(SiceLoggerAspect.java:162)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
        at com.sice.turbolib.config.service.JpegTurboLibServiceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$3.tjDecompressor(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at com.sice.bis.documents.boot.SpringBootBisApplication.main(SpringBootBisApplication.java:39)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)


My Podmanfile/Dockerfile is:
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
    ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev-profile

    # Copy the JAR file to the workdir
    COPY /myapi-boot/target/myapi-boot.jar /myapi-boot.jar

    ENTRYPOINT [\
    "java",\
    "-Xms256m",\
    "-Xmx512m",\
    "-jar",\
    "-Djava.library.path=/libjpeg-turbo/bin/",\
    "-Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}",\
    "/myapi-boot.jar"\
    ]

The docker run command is:
docker run --name apiturbo -p 9026:9026 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev-profile" --mount type=bind,source=/home/bis/BIS_Interfaces_Deploy/config/myapi/libjpeg-turbo/bin/,target=/libjpeg-turbo/bin/  myapi

If I run the jar locally (without docker container) and windows to use "-Djava.library.path=", it is working fine.
Does anyone have solution to this problem?
Thanks in advanced

Could you please [edit] to add output of ldd /libjpeg-turbo/bin/libturbojpeg.so (run inside the container) to your question? (ldd tells us what the dependencies of that library are, and how those dependencies are satisfied; if your container doesn't have something libturbojpeg needs, or libturbojpeg just isn't in the specified directory at all, that's the easiest way to get this problem).

Solution Install the library and to rename the link:
libturbojpeg.so.0.3.0 to liblibturbojpeg.so
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev-profile

# Instalar wget
RUN microdnf install -y wget

# Descargar el archivo RPM
RUN wget https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg- 
turbo/releases/download/3.0.2/libjpeg-turbo-official-3.0.2.x86_64.rpm

# Instalar rpm
RUN microdnf install -y rpm

# Instalar pkg-config
RUN microdnf install -y pkgconf-pkg-config

# Instalar sudo
RUN microdnf install -y sudo

RUN rpm -i libjpeg-turbo-official-3.0.2.x86_64.rpm

RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN mv /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libturbojpeg.so.0.3.0 /opt/libjpeg- 
turbo/lib64/liblibturbojpeg.so

# Copy the JAR file to the workdir
COPY /myapi-boot/target/myapi-boot.jar /myapi-boot.jar

ENTRYPOINT [\
"java",\
"-Xms256m",\
"-Xmx512m",\
"-jar",\
"-Djava.library.path=/libjpeg-turbo/bin/",\
"-Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}",\
"/myapi-boot.jar"\
]

IMPORTANT: liblibturbojpeg.so
